# Android 27: LogLogcatRule and RuleLoggingUtils replacement?

Tags: android, testing, logging

How does one test log output for Android classes. Prior to Android 27 [LogLogcatRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/logging/LogLogcatRule.html) and related classes like [RuleLoggingUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/logging/RuleLoggingUtils.html) served these purposes, but it appears they were removed.